# PDO fetchAll returns object in array or array in array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an annoying problem where whatever I tell `PDO` to return an array or object, it always puts it inside another array. ie.:

```
Array (
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Test Topper [urlName] => test-topper )
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Test Topper [urlName] => test-topper )
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => adfg dfg [urlName] => adfg-dfg ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => adfg dfg [urlName] => adfg-dfg )
)
```

How do I stop this behaviour so I end up with:

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => Test Topper [urlName] => test-topper ) 
[1] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Test Topper [urlName] => test-topper )
[2] => stdClass Object ( [name] => adfg dfg [urlName] => adfg-dfg ) 
[3] => stdClass Object ( [name] => adfg dfg [urlName] => adfg-dfg )
```

So I can access properties using `$data->name` instead of `$data[0]->name`?

Here is the PHP responsible for fetching the data:

```
public function fetchToppersAction($type, $orderBy, $limit)
{
    $PDOParams = array() ;
    $SQL = 'SELECT name, urlName FROM toppers_images, toppers
            LEFT JOIN meta_descriptions AS md ON md.topperId = toppers.id
            ' ;
    if($type)
    {
        $SQL .= 'WHERE typeId = ?' ;
        array_push($PDOParams, $type) ;
    }
    $SQL .= 'ORDER BY ? LIMIT ?' ;
    array_push($PDOParams, $orderBy, $limit) ;

    $r = $this->db->prepare($SQL) ;
    $r->execute($PDOParams) ;
    return $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ;
}
```

Comment: You called `fetchAll()` which returns an array of arrays (or objects), because it is expecting to return multiple rows. If you know you only have one row you want to return, either use `fetch()` instead (sensible option) or do `current($r->fetchAll())` (a bit silly but it will work)

Comment: Please review your question. Even this has been edited now by peers, it still is not comprehensible for what exactly you're looking for because the example you give is **not possible in PHP**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible this way..

How you can call `$data->name` whgen you have multiple name?

Instead of do like this

```
   /* 
    * $dataArray is the array which you are getting from $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    *
    */

  foreach($dataArray as $data){
    echo $data->name;
   }
```